# Deferred Medical

Tags: faa, medical

I applied for a first class medical over six months ago that was deferred due to a few medical problems I’ve had in the past,Some stemming from early  childhood. They included a surgery from when I was 9 years old and also thyroid disease that I developed in late teenage years. A side effect of the thyroid disease was anxiety/depression that they also want to know about.The FAA requested medical records  on all these problems but I wasn’t able to track them down in time and had my current PCP write a letter stating everything was fine based on what I told him I could remember.
My questions are can I still submit the medical records that I did find?… and also being that I’ve been off and on anti depressants (currently off) will this make them deny my first class medical?

Comment: I think you should better reword he question title

Comment: @PeymanMohamadpour to what?

Comment: You may refer to [this page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your edit changed not only the title, but the entire question, and by doing so you made the existing answer look like it is non-responsive to the question. That's discouraged here. Please roll back the edit to the question text. If you'd like to ask a new question, please feel free to do that.

Comment: I rolled it back.

Answer (score 2):

The FAA wants all your records, and a letter from your PCP is very unlikely to be enough. Call the AMCD or your regional flight surgeon and ask for an extension to get your records. If you send incomplete records, expect to wait many months just to receive a letter asking for more records. If you've ascertained the records no longer exist that is also something to talk with the AMCD or your RFS about.

Being on and off antidepressants is not a good sign, but nobody can answer what the FAA will think without seeing all your medical records. This question should be directed to your AME. Some information on antidepressants is available [here](https://www.faa.gov/ame_guide/app_process/exam_tech/item47/amd/antidepressants).

Comment: The answer above sounds right. On top of that, you can apply for SODA which is where you can go though a tedious process to prove to the FAA that you can indeed fly safely even though you don’t meet the medical requirements. Not sure of all the details behind it but this may be of interest to you.

Comment: @TaylorB SODAs are specifically for conditions that are expected to be static. Colorblindness or a missing limb for example. I don't think it would be possible to get one issued for anxiety or depression.